# Some Preset data doesn't have any location information

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

is this bug ?

Today, softlayer updates the preset productions. but Below preset productions,
there is no location information.

- Preset ID

  > 257,
  >   259,
  >   241,
  >   243,
  >   245,
  >   247,
  >   263,
  >   261,
  >   251,
  >   249,
  >   265,
  >   253,
  >   255,
  >   285,
  >   367,
  >   301,
  >   359,
  >   293,
  >   361,
  >   295,
  >   369,
  >   303,
  >   363,
  >   297,
  >   365,
  >   299,
  >   379,
  >   313,
  >   377,
  >   311
- we checked but the result is []

  > https://IBM_ID:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Preset/293/Locations.json

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, some preset do not have location are standard, it means that those presets can be used for any locations.

See the documentation below:

https://softlayer.github.io/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you/